# 'value' undefined near line 3 column 12

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing, computer-vision, octave

I'm learning Computer Vision(& new to Octave/Matlab) and wrote this code in Octave:

```
function result = func_scale(img, value)
result = value .* img;
endfunction
husky = imread('Husky.jpg');
imshow(func_scale(husky, 1.5));
```

On running the file I'm getting this error:

> error: 'value' undefined near line 3 column 12 error: called from
>       func_scale at line 3 column 10

I have named the file

> func_scale.m

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you have above the program you have pasted? have you initialized or assigned a value to variable value ?

Comment: No, I haven't. I tried just now with value = 1, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a file `func_scale.m` with the content

```
function result = func_scale(img, value) 
   result = value .* img;
endfunction
```

and you call it from octave with

```
func_scale
```

obviously the parameter `img` and `value` are missing for the calculation in line 2.

To do what you want you can leave your func_scale function in the file `func_scale.m` but move the call (imread... imshow) to another file, for example `myfile.m`. You can then call this from Octave with `myfile`

Or create one file `foobar.m` which starts with `1;`, then your function definition and then your function call